# jQuery UI Datepicker -> Display list of events based on month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the jQuery UI datepicker widget and have set a few events. What I want is to display a list of monthly events below it based on the month that the user has selected. Example would be :

[image: calendar example]

<--list of events here-->

and then if they change to April, the list would update to April events. Is this possible with this widget? I have been trying and researching for a while.

Right now I have some recurring holidays set:

```
var events = {};
for(var i=2017; i < 2027; i++){
events[new Date("01/01/"+i)] = new Event("New Years Day(Closed)", "blue");
events[new Date("02/14/"+i)] = new Event("Valentines Day", "pink");
events[new Date("03/17/"+i)] = new Event("St. Patty's Day", "green");
events[new Date("07/04/"+i)] = new Event("Independence Day(Closed)", "red");
events[new Date("10/31/"+i)] = new Event("Halloween", "orange");
events[new Date("12/25/"+i)] = new Event("Christmas Day(Closed)", "red");
```

and I have captured all the events:

```
var eventList = $(".ui-datepicker").find(".ui-datepicker-month").val();
console.log(eventList);
```

which gives me:

```
Fri Dec 25 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
:
Event
Fri Dec 25 2026 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
:
Event
Fri Feb 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
:
Event
Fri Feb 14 2025 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
:
Event
Fri Jan 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
:
Event
Fri Jul 04 2025 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
:
Event
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mt1 border-left flex mr2" style="margin-left: 12px; ">
  <span> Date:</span>
  <input type="text" id="Date" name="date" placeholder="">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    function ShowEvents(month) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".ui-datepicker").height(550);
            var Html = "<div style='color:red;'> Events in " + monthNames[month - 1] + " </div>";
            Html += "<br> First Event ";
            Html += "<br> Second Event ";
            Html += "<br> Third Event ";
            $(".ui-datepicker").append(Html);
        }, 5);
    }

    $("#Date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        inline: true,
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, widget) {
            ShowEvents(month);
        }
    });
    $("#Date").focusin(function() {
        if ($(".ui-datepicker").is(':visible') == false) {
            var d = new Date();
            ShowEvents(d.getMonth() + 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Refer **[`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/uqe1btdc/12/)**

Comment: That works if it was in a popup. But it would also require me to change the code every month to update "first event, second event..."

Comment: I got it to work without a popup but it makes it so I cant highlight dates on the calendar. Thanks for your post though!

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to explain. You have to write a function like when you pass a month, the function will return events in that particular month. You need to loop through all the events and create html for that. And bind that html to calender div. That will solve your problem